# Flutter: No detecta bien el Tap, pero si hago hot reload ya lo detecta bien, ¿Como lo arreglo?

Tags: flutter, dart, programación-móvil, programacion-asincrona, realidad-aumentada

> El caso es que cuando arranco la aplicacion y pruebo a hacer tap en el plano coloca mal las esferas, pero si hago hot reload sin hacer ningun cambio las empieza a colocar perfecto.

> Puedo iniciar la aplicacion y en el mismo instante que se inicia darle a hot reload sin cargar los planos ni nada y hasta así funciona bien.
> He probado a hacerlo sin FutureBuilder y con el, no se si el fallo esta en la sintaxis, la declaracion o que no asigno bien los valores.

> Adjunto el codigo de la clase ArMeasurementScreen.dart, main.dart y Joystick.dart.

> Gracias de antemano!

```
import 'package:arcore_flutter_plugin/arcore_flutter_plugin.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_joystick/flutter_joystick.dart';
import 'package:vector_math/vector_math_64.dart' as vector;
import 'dart:math' as Math;

//GlobalKey<_ArMeasurementScreenState> myWidgetKey = GlobalKey();

/*void rebuildMyWidget() {
  myWidgetKey.currentState?.setState(() {});
}*/

class ArMeasurementScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const ArMeasurementScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<ArMeasurementScreen> createState() => _ArMeasurementScreenState();
}

class _ArMeasurementScreenState extends State<ArMeasurementScreen> {
  int selectedNodeIndex = 0;
  var contadorEsferas = 0;
  var vertical = false;
  var horizontal = false;
  late ArCoreController arCoreController;
  String distanceMessage = "";
  vector.Vector3? posicionColocar;
  String? selectedNodeName; // Nombre del nodo seleccionado
  //TENGO QUE CONTROLAR TODO EL MAPA SI O SI
  Map<String?, ArCoreNode> nodesMap = {}; // Mapa para almacenar los nodos
  Map<String?, ArCoreNode> nodesMapLinea = {};

  late Future<void> _initializeArCoreControllerFuture;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _initializeArCoreControllerFuture = _initializeArCoreController();
  }

  Future<void> _initializeArCoreController() async {
    // Aquí puedes realizar cualquier configuración o carga inicial necesaria
    // antes de mostrar el ArCoreView.

    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2)); // Simulación de carga
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Center(child: Text('AR Measurement App')),
          backgroundColor: Colors.teal,
        ),
        body: FutureBuilder<void>(
          future: _initializeArCoreControllerFuture,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
              // Cuando el Future se complete, muestra el ArCoreView.
              return buildArCoreView();
            } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
              // Si hay un error, muestra un mensaje de error.
              return Center(child: Text('Error al inicializar ARCore'));
            } else {
              // Mientras el Future está pendiente, muestra un indicador de carga.
              return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
            }
          },
        ),
        // Otros widgets como FloatingActionButton, etc.
        floatingActionButton: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
          children: [
            FloatingActionButton(
              onPressed: _switchNode,
              tooltip: 'Switch Node',
              child: const Icon(Icons.swap_horiz),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 10), // Espacio entre botones
            FloatingActionButton(
              onPressed: _onButtonPressed,
              tooltip: 'Add Node',
              child: const Icon(Icons.add),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 10), // Espacio entre botones
          ],
        ),
        // Agregar botones para controlar la esfera
        bottomNavigationBar: _buildControlButtons(),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget buildArCoreView() {
    // Aquí construyes y retornas tu widget ArCoreView
    // junto con los demás widgets como el Joystick, etc.
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Stack(children: [
          ArCoreView(
            onArCoreViewCreated: _onArCoreViewCreated,
            enableTapRecognizer: true,
            enablePlaneRenderer: true, // Asegúrate de que esté habilitado
            enableUpdateListener: true,
          ),
          //JOYSTICK
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
              child: Joystick(
                mode: JoystickMode.all,
                listener: (StickDragDetails details) {
                  _moveSphere(
                      vector.Vector3(details.x / 200, -details.y / 200, 0));
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
          //JOYSTICK
          const Center(
              child: Icon(Icons.add, color: Colors.white)), // Mira en el centro
          Positioned(
            top: 20, // Ajusta la posición según necesites
            left: 10,
            right: 10,
            child: Text(distanceMessage,
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.white)),
          ),
          Positioned(
            top: 75, // Ajusta la posición según necesites
            left: 10,
            right: 10,
            child: Text(planeOrientation,
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.white)),
          ),
        ]),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildControlButtons() {
    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
      children: <Widget>[
        IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_upward),
            onPressed: () => _moveSphere(vector.Vector3(0, 0.01, 0))),
        IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_downward),
            onPressed: () => _moveSphere(vector.Vector3(0, -0.01, 0))),
        IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
            onPressed: () => _moveSphere(vector.Vector3(-0.01, 0, 0))),
        IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_forward),
            onPressed: () => _moveSphere(vector.Vector3(0.01, 0, 0))),

        // Botones para manejar el eje Z
        IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.zoom_out),
            onPressed: () => _moveSphere(vector.Vector3(0, 0, -0.01))),
        IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.zoom_in),
            onPressed: () => _moveSphere(vector.Vector3(0, 0, 0.01))),

        IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.delete), onPressed: _removeSelectedSphere),
      ],
    );
  }

  void _onArCoreViewCreated(ArCoreController controller) {
    arCoreController = controller;
    controller.onPlaneTap = _onPlaneTap;
    controller.onNodeTap = _onNodeTap;
    controller.onPlaneDetected = _onPlaneDetected;
  }

  void _switchNode() {
    if (nodesMap.isEmpty) {
      return;
    }

    // Obtiene los nombres de los nodos en una lista
    List<String?> nodeNames = nodesMap.keys.toList();

    // Si solo hay un nodo, selecciona ese
    if (nodesMap.length == 1) {
      selectedNodeName = nodeNames.first;
    } else {
      // Encuentra el índice del nodo actualmente seleccionado
      int currentIndex = nodeNames.indexOf(selectedNodeName);

      // Calcula el índice del siguiente nodo
      int nextIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % nodeNames.length;

      // Selecciona el siguiente nodo
      selectedNodeName = nodeNames[nextIndex];
    }

    // Actualiza la posición del nodo seleccionado
    if (selectedNodeName != null) {
      setState(() {
        posicionColocar = nodesMap[selectedNodeName]?.position?.value;
      });
    }
  }

  //CREO LINEA ENTRE NODOS

  void createLineBetweenNodes(ArCoreNode node1, ArCoreNode node2) {
    final vector.Vector3? startPosition = node1.position?.value;
    final vector.Vector3? endPosition = node2.position?.value;

    const int numberOfDots = 3; // Define cuántos puntos quieres en la línea
    final vector.Vector3 direction = endPosition! - startPosition!;
    final double length = direction.length;
    final vector.Vector3 increment =
        direction.normalized() * (length / numberOfDots);

    for (double i = 1; i <= numberOfDots; i++) {
      final vector.Vector3 dotPosition = startPosition + (increment * i);

      final ArCoreSphere dot = ArCoreSphere(
        materials: [ArCoreMaterial(color: Colors.white)],
        radius: 0.004, // Tamaño del punto
      );

      final ArCoreNode dotNode = ArCoreNode(
        shape: dot,
        position: dotPosition,
      );
      nodesMapLinea[dotNode.name] = dotNode;
      arCoreController.addArCoreNode(dotNode);
    }
  }

  //FIN AGREGAR LINEA ENTRE NODOS

  double calculateDistanceBetweenNodes(String nodeName1, String nodeName2) {
    final vector.Vector3? nodePosition1 = nodesMap[nodeName1]?.position?.value;
    final vector.Vector3? nodePosition2 = nodesMap[nodeName2]?.position?.value;

    if (nodePosition1 != null && nodePosition2 != null) {
      return (nodePosition1 - nodePosition2).length;
    } else {
      //print("Uno o ambos nodos no se encuentran en el mapa");
      return 0.0;
    }
  }

  void onCalculateDistancePressed() {
    if (nodesMap.length >= 2) {
      // Asumiendo que tienes los nombres de los dos nodos que quieres medir
      String? nodeName1 = nodesMap.keys.elementAt(0);
      String? nodeName2 = nodesMap.keys.elementAt(1);

      double distance = calculateDistanceBetweenNodes(nodeName1!, nodeName2!);
      //CREA LA LINEA DESCOMENTARLO
      createLineBetweenNodes(
          nodesMap.values.first, nodesMap.values.elementAt(1));

      // Actualizar la variable de mensaje con la distancia
      setState(() {
        distanceMessage =
            "La distancia entre ambos puntos es: ${distance.toStringAsFixed(2)} metros";
      });
    } else {
      setState(() {
        distanceMessage = "No hay suficientes nodos para calcular la distancia";
      });
    }
  }

  //OPTIMIZAR MOVER LAS ESFERAS
  /*
  void _moveSphere(vector.Vector3 direction) {
    if (selectedNodeName != null) {
        final existingNode = nodesMap[selectedNodeName];
        if (existingNode != null) {
            existingNode.position?.value += direction;
            // Otras actualizaciones necesarias
        }
    }
}
   */

  //**********************************************************************************************************************************************************

  //DateTime? lastUpdate;
  void _moveSphere(vector.Vector3 direction) {
    if (selectedNodeName != null) {
      /*nodeGeneral?.position?.value += direction;
      arCoreController?.addArCoreNode(nodeGeneral!);*/
      //final currentTime = DateTime.now();

      // Verificar si ha pasado el tiempo suficiente desde la última actualización
      //if (lastUpdate == null || currentTime.difference(lastUpdate!).inMilliseconds > 500) { // 500 milisegundos como ejemplo
      final node = ArCoreNode(
        shape: ArCoreSphere(
          materials: [ArCoreMaterial(color: Colors.red.shade200)],
          radius: 0.01,
        ),
        position: posicionColocar,
      );

      node.position?.value += direction;
      setState(() {
        posicionColocar = (node.position!.value + direction);
      });

      nodesMap.remove(selectedNodeName);
      arCoreController.removeNode(nodeName: selectedNodeName);
      _removeLineNodes(); // Llama a esta función para eliminar los nodos de la línea

      selectedNodeName = node.name;
      arCoreController.addArCoreNode(node);
      nodesMap[node.name] = node; // Almacenar el nodo en el mapa
      onCalculateDistancePressed();

      // Guardar el tiempo de esta actualización
      //lastUpdate = currentTime;
      //}
    }
  }

  //**********************************************************************************************************************************************************
  /* APLICAR ESTE MOVE SPHERE
  void _moveSphere(vector.Vector3 direction) {
    if (selectedNodeName != null) {
      final node = nodesMap[selectedNodeName];
      if (node != null) {
        vector.Vector3 newPosition;
        if (horizontal) {
          // Mover solo en eje X y Z para planos horizontales
          newPosition = vector.Vector3(
            node.position.value.x + direction.x,
            node.position.value.y, // Mantener la posición Y actual
            node.position.value.z + direction.z,
          );
        } else if (vertical) {
          // Mover solo en eje X y Y para planos verticales
          newPosition = vector.Vector3(
            node.position.value.x + direction.x,
            node.position.value.y + direction.y,
            node.position.value.z, // Mantener la posición Z actual
          );
        } else {
          // No se ha detectado ningún plano, comportamiento por defecto
          newPosition = node.position.value + direction;
        }

        // Actualizar la posición del nodo
        setState(() {
          node.position.value = newPosition;
        });

        // Agregar el nodo actualizado al controlador ARCore
        arCoreController.updateNode(node: node);
      }
    }
  }
  */
  //**********************************************************************************************************************************************************
  void _removeLineNodes() {
    List<String> nodeNamesToRemove = [];

    nodesMapLinea.forEach((key, value) {
      nodeNamesToRemove.add(key!);
    });

    for (String nodeName in nodeNamesToRemove) {
      arCoreController.removeNode(nodeName: nodeName);
      nodesMapLinea.remove(nodeName);
    }
  }

  void _removeSelectedSphere() {
    if (selectedNodeName != null && nodesMap.keys.contains(selectedNodeName)) {
      arCoreController.removeNode(nodeName: selectedNodeName!);
      nodesMap.remove(selectedNodeName);
      _removeLineNodes(); // Llama a esta función para eliminar los nodos de la línea
      selectedNodeName = null;
      setState(() {
        distanceMessage = "No hay suficientes nodos para calcular la distancia";
      });
    }
  }

//SEGUIR CON LA LOGICA DE QUE SOLO PUEDA HABER 2 ESFERAS EN ESCENA/ EN EL MAPA
  void _onButtonPressed() {
    if (posicionColocar != null && nodesMap.length < 2) {
      // Coloca un nodo en la última posición conocida
      contadorEsferas += 1;
      _addSphereNode(posicionColocar!);
    } else {
      // Manejar el caso en que no se ha detectado ninguna superficie
    }
  }

  void _addSphereNode(vector.Vector3 position) {
    final node = ArCoreNode(
      shape: ArCoreSphere(
        materials: [ArCoreMaterial(color: Colors.red.shade200)],
        radius: 0.01,
      ),
      position: position,
    );
    arCoreController.addArCoreNode(node);
    nodesMap[node.name] = node; // Almacenar el nodo en el mapa
    onCalculateDistancePressed();
  }

  vector.Vector3? getNodePosition(String nodeName) {
    ArCoreNode? node = nodesMap[nodeName];
    if (node != null) {
      return node.position?.value;
    } else {
      //print("Nodo no encontrado");
      return null;
    }
  }

  String planeOrientation = '';
  /*void analyzeRotationMatrix(vector.Matrix4 rotationMatrix) {
    // Convertir la matriz de rotación a un cuaternión
    vector.Quaternion quaternion = vector.Quaternion.fromRotation(rotationMatrix.getRotation());

    // Obtener el ángulo y el eje de rotación
    double angle = 2 * Math.acos(quaternion.w);
    double s = Math.sqrt(1 - quaternion.w * quaternion.w); // Prevenir división por cero
    vector.Vector3 axis;
    if (s < 0.001) {
      axis = vector.Vector3(quaternion.x, quaternion.y, quaternion.z); // Si s es cero, el ángulo es 0 y el eje puede ser cualquier vector unitario
    } else {
      axis = vector.Vector3(
        quaternion.x / s, // Normalizar el eje
        quaternion.y / s,
        quaternion.z / s,
      );
    }

    // Determinar la orientación del plano
    if (axis.z.abs() > 0.5) {
      planeOrientation = "Plano detectado es probablemente vertical";
    } else {
      planeOrientation = "Plano detectado es probablemente horizontal";
    }
  }*/

  /*void analyzeQuaternionRotation(vector.Quaternion quaternion) {
    // Aquí analizas el cuaternión para determinar la orientación del plano
    // Puedes, por ejemplo, obtener el ángulo y el eje de rotación del cuaternión
    vector.Vector3 axis = vector.Vector3.zero();
    double angle = 2 * Math.acos(quaternion.w);
    axis = quaternion.axis;


    // Lógica para determinar si el plano es horizontal o vertical
  }*/
  void analyzeQuaternionRotation(vector.Quaternion quaternion) {
    // Calcular el ángulo de rotación y el eje
    vector.Vector3 axis = quaternion.axis;
    double angle = 2 * Math.acos(quaternion.w);

    // Normalizar el ángulo a un rango de 0 a 360 grados
    angle = angle * 180 / Math.pi;
    if (angle > 180) {
      angle = 360 - angle;
    }

    // Determinar la orientación del plano
    // Un plano horizontal generalmente tendrá un eje de rotación cercano a (1, 0, 0) o (-1, 0, 0)
    // Un plano vertical generalmente tendrá un eje de rotación cercano a (0, 1, 0) o (0, -1, 0)
    if ((axis.x.abs() > 0.9 && axis.y.abs() < 0.1) ||
        (axis.x.abs() < 0.1 && axis.y.abs() > 0.9)) {
      planeOrientation = ('El plano es horizontal');
      horizontal = true;
      vertical = false;
    } else {
      planeOrientation = ('El plano es vertical');
      horizontal = false;
      vertical = true;
    }
  }

  void _onPlaneTap(List<ArCoreHitTestResult> hits) {
    if (nodesMap.length < 2) {
      //***********************************SEGUIR AQUI******************************************
      //****************************************************************************************
      //SI INICIO LA APLICACION SE COLOCA MAL, PERO CUANDO HAGO HOT
      // RELOAD CAMBIANDO UN PARAMETRO DE X O Z ES COMO QUE SE COLOCA BIEN,
      // SI LO COLOCO EN 0 SE COLOCA PERFECTO DESPUES DEL HOT RELOAD,
      // SIN EL HOT RELOAD PARECE QUE HAY QUE CAMBIAR LA X O LA Z, GENERALMENTE LA Z
      //****************************************************************************************
      setState(() {
        posicionColocar =
            hits.first.pose.translation + vector.Vector3(0, -0.15, 0);
        contadorEsferas += 1;
      });
      _addSphereNode(posicionColocar!);
      hits.removeAt(0);
    }
  }

  void _onNodeTap(String text) {
    setState(() {
      selectedNodeName = text;
    });
    vector.Vector3? posi = getNodePosition(text);
    setState(() {
      posicionColocar = posi;
    });
    setState(() {
      selectedNodeIndex = nodesMap.keys.toList().indexOf(text);
    });
    //arCoreController?.removeNode(nodeName: text);
    //posicionColocar = pos;
  }

  void _onPlaneDetected(ArCorePlane plane) {
    final hit = plane;

    // Obtener el cuaternión de rotación del 'hit'
    final quaternionRotation = vector.Quaternion(
        hit.centerPose!.rotation.x,
        hit.centerPose!.rotation.y,
        hit.centerPose!.rotation.z,
        hit.centerPose!.rotation.w);

    // Analizar el cuaternión para determinar la orientación del plano
    analyzeQuaternionRotation(quaternionRotation);

    /*ArCoreNode planeNode;

    // Crea el material según el tipo de plano
    ArCoreMaterial material = ArCoreMaterial();
    if (horizontal) {

      material = ArCoreMaterial(
        color: Colors.red,
        // Agrega propiedades adicionales si necesitas
      );
    } else if (vertical) {
      material = ArCoreMaterial(
        color: Colors.yellow,
        // Agrega propiedades adicionales si necesitas
      );*/

    // Crea un cubo como marcador del plano
    /*ArCoreCube cube = ArCoreCube(
        size: vector.Vector3(0.1, 0.1, 0.1), // Ajusta el tamaño según necesites
        materials: [material],
      );*/

    // Crea y agrega el nodo del plano a tu escena AR
    // En la función donde creas el nodo del cubo
    /*ArCoreNode planeNode = ArCoreNode(
        shape: cube,
        position: vector.Vector3(plane.centerPose!.translation.x, plane.centerPose!.translation.y, plane.centerPose!.translation.z),
        rotation: plane.centerPose?.rotation,
      );
    }*/
/*
    ArCoreCube cube = ArCoreCube(
      size: vector.Vector3(0.1, 0.1, 0.1), // Ajusta el tamaño según necesites
      materials: [material],
    );

    // Crea y agrega el nodo del plano a tu escena AR
    // En la función donde creas el nodo del cubo
    planeNode = ArCoreNode(
        shape: cube,
        position: vector.Vector3(plane.centerPose!.translation.x, plane.centerPose!.translation.y - 0.15, plane.centerPose!.translation.z),
        rotation: plane.centerPose?.rotation,
      );

    arCoreController?.addArCoreNode(planeNode);*/
  }
}
```

Comment: El main: import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:screentouch/ArMeasurementScreen.dart';

void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(ArMeasurementScreen());
}

Comment: La clase Joystick: class JoyStick extends StatefulWidget {
  final double radius;
  final double stickRadius;
  final Function(double, double) callback;

  const JoyStick({
    super.key,
    required this.radius,
    required this.stickRadius,
    required this.callback,
  });

  @override
  _JoyStickState createState() => _JoyStickState();
}class _JoyStickState extends State<JoyStick> {
.........